# Facing issues with declaring multiple solidity versions in my hardhat config file

Tags: javascript, interface, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

```
solidity: {
        compilers: [{ version: "0.8.8" }, { version: "0.6.0" }],
    },
```

here in my hardhat config I am running into this error:

The Solidity version pragma statement in these files doesn't match any of the configured compilers in your config. Change the pragma or configure additional compiler versions in your hardhat config.

```
contracts/test/MockV3Aggregator.sol (^0.6.0import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol")
```

The syntax for the MockV3Aggregator.sol here:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
```

I tried to declare multiple solidity versions in my hardhat config file to be able to compile code from different solidity smart contracts and interfaces with different solidity versions but it is showing an error in compiling the interface version

Answer (score 1):

```
// this is for default contract
const DEFAULT_COMPILER_SETTINGS = {
  version: '0.8.8',
}

// this is for version 6.0.0
const LOWEST_OPTIMIZER_COMPILER_SETTINGS = {
  version: '0.6.0',
  settings: {
    evmVersion: 'istanbul',
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1_000,
    },
    metadata: {
      bytecodeHash: 'none',
    },
  },
}
```

then in config

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [DEFAULT_COMPILER_SETTINGS],
    //pointing your MockV3Aggregator.sol
    overrides: {
      'contracts/MockV3Aggregator.sol': LOW_OPTIMIZER_COMPILER_SETTINGS,
     
    },
  },
```

also in your other contracts set this

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
```